# R - using values in row to determine what column to select to fill a field

Tags: r, dataframe

For example:
I have a data frame named table:

```
Cn c1 c2 c3 c4
c3 1  3  5  6
c2 4  6  7  9
```

I want to create a new column, with the value contained in the column, with column name in Cn, so it'll look like:

```
Cn c1 c2 c3 c4 NewCol
c3 1  3  5  6  5
c2 4  6  7  9  6
```

My attempt was `table$NewCol<-table[,table$Cn]`

However, instead of returning 1 value per row, the `table$NewCol[1]` is a vector containing (5, 3), which refers to the (c3, c2) in the Cn column, meaning that for each row, all rows of Cn are looked up and put into the new variable.

I know I can use loops but I'm dealing with a 7 million+ record data frame, and looping is very slow.

Anyone have any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: Something like `df$NewCol <- diag(as.matrix(df[match(df$Cn, names(df))]))` might work, where `df` is the data

Comment: Thanks I'll go ahead and try that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use matrix indexing of the desired row and column values to extract. 
I used `dat` as your data.frame name.

```
dat[-1][cbind(seq_along(dat$Cn),match(as.character(dat$Cn),names(dat[-1])))]
#[1] 5 6
```

As in:

```
sel <- cbind(seq_along(dat$Cn),match(as.character(dat$Cn),names(dat[-1])))
sel    

#      row  col
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    2

dat[-1][sel]
#[1] 5 6
```

Timing on 7M rows and your 4 column example is about 0.4 seconds.

```
dat2 <- dat[sample(1:2,7e6,replace=TRUE),]
nrow(dat2)
#[1] 7000000
system.time({
  sel <- cbind(seq_along(dat2$Cn),match(as.character(dat2$Cn),names(dat2[-1])))
  dat2$newcol <- dat2[-1][sel]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.33    0.07    0.39
```

Comment: quality work! My only defence with using `set` will be for memory efficiency (no need to create the 7 million row matrix `sel`)

Comment: Since it seems there is no matrix-like indexing for `data.table`s, you could always cut this solution up into manageable blocks of a few hundred thousand rows in a loop. It should still only take a matter of seconds to run and would avoid the need to assign a huge matrix.

Comment: This is great thanks! I used the first method and it took a few minutes so that's fine by me.

Answer (score 3):

Use `mapply` to apply `[.data.frame` as you move along each row and d$Cn.

```
 table$NewCol <- mapply(i = seq_along(d[['Cn']]),
         j= d[['Cn']],
     FUN = function(i,j,x) x[i,j,drop=TRUE],
     MoreArgs=list(x=d))
```

If speed and efficiency are of concern, use `data.table` and `set` (This loop *is* efficient)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)

for(i in seq_len(nrow(d))){
  set(d,j='newCol', i=i, value= d[[d[['Cn']][i]]][i])
}
```

Comment: I'm looping and hoping it'll run overnight, if something goes wrong I'll definitely try your solutions. Thank you!

Comment: @user53646 - You definitely won't need a whole night to run the `data.table` solution.  I'm guessing it will be less than one minute.

Comment: @user53646 Use `data.table` and `set` takes about 1 minute with 50 columns and 1 million rows....